# Select multiple columns, tables from a specific id and timestamp

Tags: sql

I am trying to select multiple columns, tables for a specific id and timestamp.
For example, I am trying to retrieve data from the reservation, trip, and session table for id=fff222 from 02/14/2022-02/15/2022 between in UTC timestamp. I tried this implementation however it gave me more rows than when I manually search each table. Where did I went wrong
Updated implementation:

```
SELECT reservation.reason, reservation.state, reservation.inserted_at, From reservation JOIN session Join trip on
trip.sessionId=trip.sessionId and trip.sessionId=session.sessionId
(here something missing)
WHERE trip.sessionId='fff222' ORDER BY session.inserted_at between '2022-02-14 00:00:00' and '2022-02-15 23:59:59'
```

Any suggesstion to get the same exact amount of rows when searching each table manually

Comment: You have to join the tables because without a join condition you get a cartesian product of the rows.

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you. Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and *only* that RDBMS. Also it's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for **30 years**; there is no reason to be using that old implicit JOIN syntax any more. (Also, you don't delimit your clauses in the `WHERE`.)

Comment: @Larnu there is no joining here at all...

Comment: And there is no `CROSS JOIN` explicit syntax at all either, @Shadow . Though clearly, from the question, it appears there there is supposed to be a relationship, and thus an `INNER JOIN` is likely wanted.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables. Try this

```
SELECT 
    reservation.reason,
    reservation.state, 
    reservation.inserted_at,
    session.reason,
    session.state,
    session.inserted_at,
    trip.reason, 
    trip.state, 
    trip.inserted_at 
FROM 
    reservation JOIN session JOIN trip
ON 
    trip.sessionId = reservation.sessionId AND 
    trip.sessionId = session.sessionId
WHERE 
    trip.sessionId='fff222'
ORDER BY 
    vtq.session.inserted_at
```

Comment: This'll likely error; you have 2 `JOIN`s but only 1 `ON` clause.

Comment: Actually the join conditions are two and they are separated by an `AND` clause.

Comment: I updated my post but got messier

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your query to:

- use the `join` keyword for joins
- add join conditions
- change the order of joins to the natural "bottom-up" order
- add aliases and formatting for readability

Try this:

```
select
  r.reason,
  r.state,
  r.inserted_at,
  s.reason,
  s.state,
  s.inserted_at,
  t.reason,
  t.state,
  t.inserted_at
from trip t 
join session s on s.id = t.sessionId
join reservation r on r.sessionId = t.sessionId
where t.sessionId = 'fff222'
and s.inserted_at between '2022-02-14 00:00:00' and '2022-02-15 23:59:59'
order by s.inserted_at
```

Comment: the s, t, r are confusing with session, trip, and reservation inserted Can you update

Comment: @engicode123 oops! thanks - fixed.

Comment: plus some other errors corrected...

Comment: I tried your way however it gave error saying operator does not exist integer= character varying

Comment: @engicode123 what database are you using? (oracle?)

Comment: I tried the followng way above hwever I get duplicate results. So I tried group_by and distinct but silll receivig more rows then expected